# Laravel 7 with Vue js execution without php artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-artisan, serve

I am using Vue js with Laravel in large application for better user experience. Used API call to communicate Vue js front end with Laravel Backend. It's working fine when I use command prompt to execute the application and the commands are "php artisan serve" and "npm run watch".

As I need this to be executed in Live Server, I have renamed "server.php" to "index.php" then moved ".htaccess" file from public folder to root folder. When I execute this in browser "http://localhost/projectname" it's not working but when I use Laravel without vue js its working fine.

Can anyone please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: re ask your question with more clarification like what server are you trying to host on. is it a shared hosting with cpanel or dedicated

Comment: You don't need to run `php artisan serve` and `npm run watch` in the server. If you could let us know what type of server you have for you app i.e shared or dedicated then we can help. 

For vue js run `npm run build` to compile and minify the js files before the deployment.

Comment: We are using dedicated linux hosting. Accessing the files and db through plesk panel.